# Как сделать бесконечную отправку сообщений в Discord.JS

Tags: javascript, функции, бот, discord

Подскажите, у меня есть код, как сделать чтобы сообщение отправлялось бесконечно, или хотя-бы очень много раз.

```html
     if(message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(".!.spamm")){

        message.reply("OAOAOAOAOOAOAOAOOAOAOAOAOAOOAOAOAOOAOAOAOA | Crashed by MCBOT");

    }
```

Comment: `setInterval(() => sendMessageHandle(), 1000);` - с интервалом в одну секунду будет запускать функцию.

Answer (score 0):

```js
if(message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith('.!.spamm')){
    for(let k=0; k !== 10; k++){
        message.reply('OAOAOAOAOOAOAOAOOAOAOAOAOAOOAOAOAOOAOAOAOA | Crashed by MCBOT');
    }
}
```

*Thonk?*

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать `set interval` для этого.

```js
if(message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith('.!.spamm')){
    setInterval(() => {
        message.channel.send('OAOAOAOAOOAOAOAOOAOAOAOAOAOOAOAOAOOAOAOAOA | Crashed by MCBOT');
    }, 1000)
}
```